# I can't install Epson L395 on Ubuntu 16,04 LTS

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I'm a new user of Linux and don't have any knowledge about programming. Just to tell you that the answers will need to be written as you would write for a newbie.

I've already read some answers about it but they don't work or I'm doing something wrong.
Some answers refer me to a list where I can download drivers but L395 is not on that list. 
Can somebody please explain me step by step what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
```

Connect the printer by, may I assume, USB. Click the dash, which is used to launch programs and settings. Look for Settings and select Printers. Select 'Add New Printer'. When asked for the driver, select 'Select from database...' You should now find your Epson L395.

Comment: It is better to install proprietary drivers. https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Comment: I followed your steps Chili555 and it did the job. The printer is working now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate it.